# How to manipulate standard button from a custom object?

Tags: apex, trigger, button, standard

I'm having an issue with standard button on my custom object.

I have a standard button "Clone" and i would like to manipulate it through my apex class but i can't find a way to do something like this, maybe it is not possible.

I want to do that because i have made an approval process on a custom object and i would like my user's to be able to clone what they made.

But actually i have a trigger that block the Clone action.

So i would like to say to the trigger to doesn't trigger when the Action is to Clone.

Let me know if i'm clear or if it is possible to do something like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Lightning Aura Component with an APEX Controller that provides your custom Clone functionality. Then you can override the standard Clone button as described here: https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/06/12/override-standard-buttons-lightning-component/

Let me know if you have anymore questions regarding the process.